# Problema al decodificar cadena hacia UTF-8

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente cadena sobre un archivo XML:

```
seg&#56319;&#56320;n
```

la cual se obtiene al subir un fichero, la cosa esta en que no puedo regresarla a algún carácter conocido, por decirlo a ISO-8859-1 o UTF-8
por ejemplo

```
según
```

ó

```
segÃºn
```

el `mb_detect_encoding` me dice que es un utf-8

el código es el siguiente

```
fwrite($file,
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.
            // utf8_decode(
                mb_convert_encoding(
                html_entity_decode(trim($contenido))
                , 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')
                // )
            );
        fclose($file);
```

donde `$contenido` es el xml que contiene dicha cadena

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la variable `$contenido` y su valor? [Todo `XML` debe tener un `root`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp) y al no mostrar que imprimes es difícil saber si el error se debe a alguna otra cosa.

Comment: Si quisiera colocar el xml, pero son datos privados, no por mi, si no por otras personas. Gracias por la ayuda @Marcos Gallardo

Comment: Los *puntos de código* (*code points*) 56319 y 56320 que publicaste no perecen a ningún caracter válido. De hecho, están en un rango de Unicode para uso privado (propio de cada programa). Por lo tanto, deberías revisar cómo se generan y por qué son utilizados. Independientemente de si uses html_entity_decode, mb_convert_encoding o utf8_decode, no obtendrás ningún caracter válido

Answer (score 0):

Has probado con esto ?

string utf8_encode (string $data)

http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: Si, y no funciona.

Comment: Que es lo que tienes puedes agregar tu código ? @HammerffallBK

Comment: Ya puse parte del código.

Comment: Realizandolo de la manera del código expuesto, obtengo esto `segí¯¿í°€n`

Answer (score 0):

usa [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php), ejemplo:

```
$valor_decodificado = mb_convert_encoding($valor_codificado ,'HTML-ENTITIES','utf-8');
```

o `utf8_encode()`, ejemplo:

```
$valor_decodificado = utf8_encode($valor_codificado);
```

---

Revisando los codigos html del string que mencionas al parecer son erroneos, tanto `&#56319;` como  `&#56320;`

```
seg&#56319;&#56320;n
```

debería ser únicamente `&#250;`

```
 seg&#250;n
```

para que al decodificar se muestre correctamente la palabra:

> según

Comment: Eso convierte a entidades html, como `htmlentities`

Comment: mmm no deseas cambiar el string seg&#56319;&#56320;n a según ? :|

Comment: Yo supongo que es según, pero el detalle no es cambiarlo a mano, tengo miles de ficheros con ese problema, no se cual es la cadena correcta o si es directamente un error.

Comment: @HammerffallBK mal de mi parte por no revisar correctamente, de hecho el código que se tiene no existe, al parecer debe ser  seg&#250;n para que se pueda convertir a "según", de esta forma incluso con lo que propone Alejandro puede funcionar.

Comment: @HammerffallBK los códigos &#56319;    y     &#56320; no existen =P

Comment: Al aplicar mb_convert_encoding, obtengo lo siguiente `segí¯¿í°€n`, de HTML-ENTITIES a UTF-8

Comment: @HammerffallBK me parece que esos códigos no son correctos, trata con seg&#250;n  y debe funcionar correctamente.